# '__bridge_transfer' casts have no effect when not using ARC

Tags: objective-c, casting, automatic-ref-counting

I've got a bit of code from an open source Objective-C library which, when I compile, gives warnings like this:

```
'__bridge_transfer' casts have no effect when not using ARC
```

The line of code that produces this is:

```
  NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrService, nil];
```

How do I get rid of these warnings?

I'm using Xcode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503).

Comment: Can you share with which open source library you got this error? Yes, the error is a result of this ARC code in your presumably MRC project. But this whole construct (doing a `__bridge_transfer` of a constant) looks a little suspicious. It would be interesting to see this line code in context of the broader open source project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are compiling ARC code as MRR.  You need to use the command line option `-fobjc-arc`, for which there is a line in the Xcode Project Settings called "Automatic Reference Counting".

Answer (score 0):

stupid solution one => turn on arc

stupid solution two

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (__bridge_transfer NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrService, nil];
#else
NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrService, nil];
#endif
```

Comment: as ARC is becoming the 'good way to do things', I wouldn't only write NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kSecClass, kSecAttrAccount, kSecAttrService, nil];

Answer (score 0):

`CFbridgingRetain()` and `CFBridgingRelease()` can be used on ARC, GC, and MRC just fine.